# How to stop an invalid date from being sent to a database

Tags: php

I require a date to be entered in the correct format, and if it isn't then an error is shown. My PHP program looks like this:

```
    if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
      $dateErr = "Date is required";
         } else {
           $date = test_input($_POST["date"]); etc
```

This is just the standard way of showing error for an improper date format. But my problem is that even though an error is shown, there is nothing that is stopping that date (in the wrong format) from being passed into the database. When I check my database, I see that date and it is not what I want. Is there a way that a date written in the wrong format can be blocked from ending up on my database? Like a filter, I mean.

Comment: Use regex to check for required format.

Comment: An error is shown, but the input is still sent to the database?  Sounds like you're not actually stopping the logic of the page when there's a validation error.  Also, how are you able to see an invalid date in the database?  Isn't the column a date column?  If it is, what makes the date "invalid"?  If it isn't, why isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't actually show my full code. I DO have the proper pregmatch and if a date is wrongly entered, a error shows up. But my difficulty is that when you enter the wrongly formatted date, two things happen. One is that an error message shows up, but the date ALSO is passed on to the database. I should have made it clear that it wasn't a problem I'm having with regex, it's how to stop the data from being sent to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a function to check whether the date given is in the appropriate format before  you begin your db transaction. You can do this in the following approach using regular expressions as @Subhanker mentioned to match to the following format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
 if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/", $_POST['date']))
{
    //Start DB transaction here

    // Create connection
      $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

    // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // escape variables for security
     $form_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']);


     $sql="INSERT INTO dates_table (dates)
           VALUES ('$form_date')";

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

     echo "1 record added";

}else{
    $dateErr = "Date is required";
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Cartridgemeadow, I should have been clearer in my question. I DO have the proper code to warn a user if he/she enters the wrong date format:  if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
     $dateErr = "Date is required";                                  
   } else {
     $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
     // check if date format is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/", $date)) {
      $date = "";
      $dateErr = "Invalid date format";   But my problem is how to stop that wrongly formatted date from being sent to the database.

Comment: hey user3904805, could you please post the code which starts the DB interaction, and i could refactor it appropriately. Essentially you need to invoke the db transaction only once your date has been verified, maybe there's some steps that have been coupled together. Please post and i'll look into it! :-)

Comment: hey user3904805, I updated the post to show the control flow, could you try it out as shown above and let me know if you're still running into an error?

Comment: Cartridgemeadow, thanks for the offer to help. I hope I can give you as much info as possible so yoo have a good idea where I'm going wrong. The main program contains the following lines:<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
   
   Date: <input type="text" name="date">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $dateErr;?></span>
       <p class = "caption">yyyy-mm-dd</p>

Comment: hey user 3904805, no worries! i just created a form and the above PHP, and it worked for me, could you give it a try? be sure to change the date variable as necessary!

Comment: Cartridgemeadow, I'm VERY grateful for your time and effort. Thank you kindly. I tried to respond to you by inserting my programs (the main program and the db_link program) but received the message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" I will copy and paste the program you've just sent. Hopefully it will work just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Why use regex when PHP already offers date formats and many tools to validate a date?

Comment: You're right, we could use something like checkdate (http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) because a pure regex approach based on formatting could allow invalid dates (if not implemented thoroughly). I just thought of regex here because i wasn't sure what format the questioner wanted the date validation in (it could be mm-dd-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yy) and this was the solution I knew how to create and could have tweaked it accordingly instead of finding out all the functionalities of the tools i'm not familiar with :/ great question!

Answer (score 1):

Use the powerful DateTime class, DateTime::createFromFormat is useful here, it returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

So it will go this way:

```
    if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
  $dateErr = "Date is required";
     } else {
       $format = 'Y-m-d'; // write your format here
       $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST["date"]);
       if($date)
       {
           // add to database
       }
```

Also your database field should be set as datetime which has the format Y-m-d, so before you insert it you have to format it to Y-m-d using PHP, like:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

That will return a proper string to insert in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do your checking. No regex needed

```
$date = strtotime($_POST["date"]);
if($date === false) $dateErr = "Unrecognized Date format";
else $date = date('m/d/Y', $date); // Set your own date format here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/^(19|20)\d\d[\-\/.](0*[1-9]|1[012])[\-\/.](0*[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/", $date )){//This will match the input in format YYYY-MM-DD
//Date ok
}else{
//Invalid Date
}
```

Comment: and format what would this match? Without an expected input format the answer is not very helpful to anyone that doesn't read regex well or if they are posting a different format

Comment: @charlietfl-Oh thanks for reminding I forgot to put the format.